# Elusive icon font not working on any version of IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

The icons are working beautifully in Chrome/Firefox versions, but won't work in any version of IE for some reason. No real idea as to why that is -- I'm sure it must be something simple that I'm missing. The URL with code is here: They're being served with @font-face, and the paths are correct as far as I can tell.

http://rational-animal.co.uk/elusive

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer, finally. It was the glyphicons code in bootstrap.css that overrode the Elusive icons. All of the code beginning with and following this:

```
[class^="icon-"],
[class*=" icon-"] {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
  margin-top: 1px;
  *margin-right: .3em;
  line-height: 14px;
  vertical-align: text-top;
  background-image: url("../img/glyphicons-halflings.png");
  background-position: 14px 14px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

needed to be removed to make it work.